# Is it possible to use an internal SATA DVD/CD reader?

Tags: usb, sata, dvd

I found an old internal SATA DVD/CD reader and I connected it to my computer via a SATA-to-USB cable. While I didn't expect it to work, it was able to open/eject but the disk didn't spin.

I am guessing it is either not getting enough voltage, or I am lacking drivers, or just plain broken.

Is it possible in the first place for a internal SATA DVD/CD reader to be used externally via some port?

Comment: Many "external" drives are simply an internal drive with some kind of USB to SATA adaptor. It may be that your adaptor does not support the drive for some reason or that the drive is defective.

Comment: I got the SATA-to-USB adapter for getting data off hard drives. So it could be the reason, I'm not sure if there's a difference. While I wouldn't be surprised if it's defective, it did manage light up and open/eject disks.

Comment: Opening and ejecting is usually available as soon as power is available. Unless you mean you were able to trigger it from within your operating system.

Comment: @Seth Yes, both Windows and Mac were able to trigger it from operating system. Windows also recognized the device as "Working properly" in Device Manager.

Comment: More than likely the power supply is not large enough to power an optical drive.